# How to get nested loops in config.rb to work in Middleman?

Tags: ruby, middleman, contentful

We have been working for several years on Middleman, the static HTML site builder.  After a recent upgrade we have run into an issue that has our whole team stumped.  In the config.rb all `proxy` calls work fine until we try to run a nested loop like this:

```
data.site.datatype.each do | id, c |
         puts c
      data.site.datatype.each do | id, c2 |
         puts c2
      end
    end
```

[Note that data.site.datatype are .yaml files imported using middleman-contentful.]

The behavior is that the outer loop runs fine but the inner loop refuses to execute.

The output of the outer loop (`puts c`) shows the middleman import of the .yaml payload as follows:

```
#<Middleman::Util::EnhancedHash id="id-1" name="comp1" slug="comp1">
#<Middleman::Util::EnhancedHash id="id-2" name="comp2" slug="comp2">
```

We have been stuck on this issue for a week now so any guidance would be very welcome!

The Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'middleman', '~> 4.2'
gem 'middleman-autoprefixer', '~> 2.7'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mswin, :mingw, :jruby, :x64_mingw]
gem 'wdm', '~> 0.1', platforms: [:mswin, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
gem 'middleman-dotenv', '~> 2.0'
gem 'contentful_middleman', '~> 4.2.0'
```

Otherwise the config.rm has `activate :dotenv` and `activate :contentful`

We have gone back to https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/dynamic-pages/ and can't find anything there that helps.

Comment: Use a debugger like pry with `binding.pry` or `binding.irb` if you're using a modern Ruby version. Put it right after `puts c` and when you hit the binding, try evaluating it interactively.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I can include binding.irb in the outer loop and it returns the same info as the puts command. If I put binding.irb in the inner loop, the execution never gets to the interactive session, so it does not yield any additional insight. Even interactively walking through the script the inner loop gets skipped.

Comment: A consultant has recommended replacing `data.site.datatype.each` with `@app.data.site.datatype.each` - this appears to work fine.  We are still doing the complete testing of the site but so far so god - this appears to have solved the issue.

Comment: If you put `binding.irb` right after `puts c` and then manually type in `data.site.datatype.each do ...` what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
While we have not found any real documentation on this, here is the answer.
While the use of `data.site` works in the .html.erb templates, in config.rb the call to the data files requires `@app.data.site`.

So the example code above should read

```
@app.data.site.datatype.each do | id, c |
         puts c
      @app.data.site.datatype.each do | id, c2 |
         puts c2
      end
    end
```

The hint came from the Middleman repo:

https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/master/middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/data.rb#L15-L19

```
    # Make the internal `data_store` method available as `app.data`
    expose_to_application data: :data_store

    # Exposes `internal_data_store` to templates, to be wrapped by `data` in the context
    expose_to_template internal_data_store: :data_store
```

Comment: While this works, either this fix or the upgrade itself has caused Middleman to perform very very poorly.  The site has several thousand pages, and it is now taking 20h+ to generate the static site.